# python replace is not removing backslash from string

Tags: python, replace

Here are numerous examples where backslash is removed from. Unfortunately non is working

I have string like that

```
item = '^^\n^'
```

this should work

```
item = item.replace('\\\\n^', '')
```

for the expected result '^^' but the item stays as it is.

Python Version is 3.8.3. Any hint why it should not work ?

Comment: Shouldn't `item.replace('\n^', '')` work? The backslash in the original string isn't escaped either.

Comment: You can't remove something that's not even there in the first place.

Comment: @kwt no the backslash is used for escaping. so item.replace('\\n^', '') should but doesn't either for some wired reason

Comment: @user3732793 Per my answer below, you do not need an escape character.  kwkt's example is correct.  Try running it in your terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask why this does not work.  It doesn't work because "\n" is a single character *not* two characters.  Check it out:

```
In [7]: len("\n")                                                                                                                                 
Out[7]: 1
```

Therefore, Python recognizes the backslash in "\n" not as a escape character, but part of the single character itself.  If you want to keep the backslash, but lose the "n", you need to target the "\n" completely.

```
In [15]: item.replace("\n", "\\")                                                                                                                 
Out[15]: '^^\\^'
```

But that doesn't work, we now have two backslashes in the string, right?  Wrong, one of them is escaped!

```
In [16]: print(item.replace("\n", "\\"))                                                                                                          
^^\^
```

Escape characters can be tricky if you don't use them often.  I refresh my memory, when needed, with simple examples in IPython.

Per kwkt's comment, the solution is:

```
In [1]: item = '^^\n^'
In [2]: item.replace('\n^', '')                                                                                                                   
Out[2]: '^^'
```

Comment: thanks for the example. The expected string should be just the two ^^ with no n or backslash even not escaped.